# Incoding curl request into Java String

Tags: java, http, curl

I am trying to execute curl request through command using Java.

To accomplish this thing I am using **Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);**

But the problem I am facing is to incode curl request into String.

**Curl command**

```
  curl --data "name=hell&&email=check@gmail.com&&phone=9845123134" http://www.example.com
```

**Want to convert into Java String**

How would I do it?

Comment: You should send the HTTP request using Java directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl --data \"name=hell&&email=check@gmail.com&&phone=9845123134\" http://www.example.com");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html